# IE8 - CSS visibility: collapse - Doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Does the css visibility style "collapse" work in IE8?

The reason I ask this is because I have a div that I am trying to collapse. When I publish my website the div stays visible instead of being collapsed. But when I change it to "hidden" the div is hidden.

The reason I don't just use Hidden instead of Collapse is because I don't want the huge gap on my page.

Comment: Are you asking or telling? Actually, what are you asking?

Comment: Have you tried `collapse` as opposed to `collapsed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display: none;
```

?

Comment: exactly. in case the OP is wondering, collapse is only for table elements, and isn't supported by IE8. see http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: collapse;` is meant **only for table elements.** Use `visibility: hidden` on `<div>`s.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp

---

You'll also notice the note on that page:

> **Note:** No versions of Internet Explorer (including IE8) support the property values "inherit" or "collapse".

Comment: I realize that... I just mis-typed it in my question.

Comment: Visibility: hidden can not be used. Because it will only hide the element and not the elements space.

Comment: @PeeHaa: then the answer is to use `display: none;`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by giving visibility in css classes.

```
#PopUp.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
#PopUp.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems `visibility: collapse` can be used in IE as well. I am using it and it is working in both IE and Firefox. Dont know about other browsers apart from these two.

I have done the following:

HTML:

`<table class="intValidationTable">`

`<tr class="rangeTR" style="visibility: collapse;">`

`<tr class="listTR" style="visibility: collapse;">`

Javascript + Jquery:

`var rows = $('table.intValidationTable tr');`

`var rangeTR = rows.filter('.rangeTR');`

`var listTR = rows.filter('.listTR');`

`rangeTR.css("visibility", "visible");`

`listTR.css("visibility", "collapse");`

This should work!