# jquery: .filter().css("visibility", "collapse") not working in IE, working in FF fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, css

I have a table where in there are two dropdowns.
On selecting a value from the first dropdown, the values of the second dropdown are displayed.

For this I have written the following function which gets invoked on the `onchange` event of the first dropdown:

```
function dataTypeChanged(selectedValue){

document.getElementById("nodeInputValidation").innerHTML = "";
var rows = $('table.intValidationTable tr');
rows.filter('.rangeTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.listTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.textListTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.dateRangeTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.dateListTR').css("visibility", "collapse");

var validationTypes = document.getElementById("validationType").options;
document.getElementById("validationType").value = "";
var datatype;
for(var i=0;i<validationTypes.length;i++)
{
    datatype = validationTypes[i].value.substring(0,validationTypes[i].value.indexOf("_"));

    if(datatype != selectedValue){
        $("#validationType option[value=" + validationTypes[i].value + "]").hide();
    }else{
        $("#validationType option[value=" + validationTypes[i].value + "]").show();
    }
}
}
```

This function works perfectly fine in Firefox.
But somehow it doesn't work in IE 8.0.

**EDIT:**
Earlier I thought this might be the cause of it. But its not.

```
var rows = $('table.intValidationTable tr');
rows.filter('.rangeTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.listTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.textListTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.dateRangeTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
rows.filter('.dateListTR').css("visibility", "collapse");
```

**Seems to be the other part of the function. Code that shows/hides options of the second dropdown is not working. All the options are getting displayed currently.**

Can you guys help me with this.

Let me know if more code is required.

Comment: Have you tried display: table-row-group?

Comment: no.. can you please elaborate it a little?

Comment: No versions of Internet Explorer (including IE8) support the property values "inherit" or "collapse".

Comment: Is there any alternative to "collapse" then for IE? I am using `collapse` since I dont want to show reserved space for the rows which are hidden. Looks ugly.

Comment: Dup: [IE8 - CSS visibility: collapse - Doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431096/ie8-css-visibility-collapse-doesnt-work)

Comment: Related: [difference between “visibility:collapse” and “display:none”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695813/difference-between-visibilitycollapse-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No versions of Internet Explorer (including IE8) support the property
>   values "inherit" or "collapse".

Use `display:none;` instead.

**For example:**

```
rows.filter('.rangeTR').css("display", "none");
```

Comment: I dont seem to have any problems with `visibility: collapse`. The rows are dynamically hidden/displayed based on the value of the second dropdown!!

Comment: @DarkKnightFan It's not that they're a problem, it's just that they are not supported in IE. If you want your function to be supported in all browsers use display:none;, if only firefox/chrome then visibility:collapse :)

Comment: @DarkKnightFan So if it works in IE then what did you change to make it work?

Comment: I have created rows`<tr class="dateRangeTR" style="visibility: collapse;">` and based on the value of the second dropdown I do this: `dateRangeTR.css("visibility", "visible");` OR `dateRangeTR.css("visibility", "collapse");` as TOGGLE

Comment: This shows/hides the required rows in both IE and FF. So I guess my actual problem is in the second part of the function which I need to check again. Code that populates (hides/shows) options of the second dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

`visibility: collapse` is not implemented in IE<8

Use `display: none` to hide the table elements.

see here : [Alternative to visibility:collapse not working on IE and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487187/alternative-to-visibilitycollapse-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

and here : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility

Also check the code below :

```
if(datatype != selectedValue){
    $("#validationType option[value=" + validationTypes[i].value + "]").hide();
}else{
    $("#validationType option[value=" + validationTypes[i].value + "]").show();
}
```

maybe try adding quotes (wild guess, no real hope):

```
$("#validationType option[value='" + validationTypes[i].value + "']")
```

What version of jQuery are you using?

It would be cool to put together a jsFiddle for us.

Comment: I dont seem to have any problems with `visibility: collapse`. The rows are dynamically hidden/displayed based on the value of the second dropdown!!

Comment: Edited answer. Your "option" tags might not get selected

Comment: Yeah I too think that code is the one causing this issue. I am using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: And what version of IE is buggy?

Comment: till now I have only checked in IE8

Comment: visibility: collapse is supposed to work in IE8. The problem must come from the last lines of javascript. Try debugging the 'datatype' and 'selectedValue' variables...

Comment: The problem is with `$("#validationType option[value=" + validationTypes[i].value + "]").hide();` This thing doesnt work in IE. Any alternative to this?

Comment: Please put together a jsFiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ to recreate that bug and post the link here!

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems `visibility: collapse` can be used in IE as well. I am using it and it is working in both IE and Firefox. Dont know about other browsers apart from these two.

I have done the following:

HTML:

`<table class="intValidationTable">`

```
`<tr class="rangeTR" style="visibility: collapse;">`

`<tr class="listTR" style="visibility: collapse;">`
```

Javascript + Jquery:

`var rows = $('table.intValidationTable tr');`

`var rangeTR = rows.filter('.rangeTR');`

`var listTR = rows.filter('.listTR');`

`rangeTR.css("visibility", "visible");`

`listTR.css("visibility", "collapse");`

This should work!

Regarding my question, I guess the second part of the code is erroneous. Need to check that.